# Scala beginner for-comprehensions and functions

Tags: scala, yield, for-comprehension

Hey guys i am new to scala and i dont knowe what i am doing wrrong to get the right typ into the yield statement:

```
def prim(n:Int): (Boolean, List[Int]) = divsers(n) -> List(1,n) //flatMap for-comprehensions

def divsers(n:Int):Boolean=
 (for{
    d <- 1 to n
    if((n%d)->0)
   }yield(d) // <- what i need to put here to make it work with the function prim?
  )
 prim(11);
```

I just want to test if a number is a prime number. I realy have to say that i got realy problems with the syntac and typs.Even if i put just "true" in yield it dont work?

Comment: i dont knowe why someone give me -1 ? you dont need to writte the sultion but just give me a tip to solve this problem. Maybe a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing all kinds of things that make no sense.

`divsers(n) -> List(1,n)` What is the point of returning a tuple who's 2nd element is a List of 2 `Int`s? The 1st `Int` is always `1` and the 2nd `Int` is always the number passed as an argument to `prim()`.

`if((n%d)->0)` You've created another tuple here. You probably mean to say `if (n%d) > 0`.

`yield ?` The `for` comprehension is walking through a sequence of numbers from `1` to `n`. Some of them will pass through your `if` condition and some won't. Now you've got a new list of numbers. How you're supposed to turn that into a `Boolean` is up to you.

Comment: ok, i delete the no sense part ( i am translating pseudocode to scala). But i still dont understand the last part. I knowe that some of the sequences are passing the if condition. But how can i get this one who passing the if condition. I thought this list would be the variable 'd'. finally i do this to turn them to boolen yield(d>0). it still dont work :( But thank you for helping.

Comment: If you do this `val nums = for {...} yield d` then you've got a variable, `nums`, with all the numbers that passed through the `if` test.  You can then test _that_ list for whatever condition you're looking for.